# Cron Job evaluating timestamp for the first time

Tags: shell, cron

---

```
timestamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d%S")

echo $timestamp
```

The cron job runs a script with the above line and the timestamp value is evaluated only for the first time.

Even when the script is run for the second time it gives the same value as first time

Comment: you mean `data` or `date`?

Comment: Maybe you mean `timestamp=$(date "+%Y%m%d%S")` ?  Without seeing more of the script I can't tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use

```
timestamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

because for every day you might conflict on the seconds... make sure you also append the hour and minute to make them unique everytime